# Background service to display toast every 2 min in android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am writing a small android app that does something in the background(i.e. service) and I want it to display a toast message after an interval of every 'x' minutes. How do I go about doing it with a broadcast listener and alarmmanager. Could somebody please write a sample code to demonstrate it.

Comment: You should consider displaying Notification instead of Toast.

Comment: i can show u way how u can achieve this.

first on bootup listener start your background class execution and set an alarm after 10 min.

implement alarm broadcast listener, in that put your notification logic and at the end of class again set alarm.

thats it

Comment: do you have any sample code for this cause I am trying to do something similar. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by using `Timer` and `TimerTask` in your `Service` class.

**1.** In your `Service` class, first create an inner class `DisplayToastTimerTask` extending from  `TimerTask` to display the `Toast` message. You have to use `Handler` with `Runnable` to show `Toast` from `TimerTask`:

```
private class DisplayToastTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Do something....

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**2.** Use `Timer` to schedule `DisplayToastTimerTask` for repeated execution with an interval of `2 min`

```
private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 120000; // 2 Minute
private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 0;

// Create new Timer
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DisplayToastTimerTask(), TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_INTERVAL);
```

**EXAMPLE:**

**#.** Here is the fully working `Service` class:**

```
//MyService.java

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private Timer mTimer;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 120000; // 2 Minute
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (mTimer != null)
            mTimer = null;

        // Create new Timer
        mTimer = new Timer();

        // Required to Schedule DisplayToastTimerTask for repeated execution with an interval of `2 min`
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DisplayToastTimerTask(), TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Cancel timer
        mTimer.cancel();
    }

    // Required to do some task
    // Here I just display a toast message "Hello world"
    private class DisplayToastTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Do something....

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**#.** You can start your `service` like below:

```
Intent intentMyService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
mContext.startService(intentMyService);
```

**#.** Don't forget to declare `MyService` class into `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application>

        <service android:name=".MyService" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: great answers man!